# database.php Laravel 4.2 error: unexpected return

Tags: php, laravel-4

Recently I added my hostname to use a local configuration on Laravel 4.2, then I added a copy of my `database.php` file and put into `app/config/local/database.php`. But when I try to do a migration o a `composer update` an error comes up:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN) in /app/config/local/database.php on line 3
```

In line 3 of this file there is indeed a *return*:

```
<?php

 return array( 
 ...
```

So I tried to put back the file in the `app/config` folder and got the same error.

Finally, I used the `database.php` file of one of my coworkers and still the same error.

Comment: can you post your database.php file ??

Comment: It is exactly like the default `database.php` file, here's a [link](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v4.2.11/app/config/database.php) to this file on the Laravel GitHub project.

Comment: you must be missing something in that file. There should be some syntax error mate.

Comment: But I used a coworker file that he is actually using and it works perfectly for him but not for me! D:

Comment: try in app start global.php dd(\Config::get('database'));  and check it give some error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this problem by copying and pasting the `database.php` from other project (copy and paste the file, not the content of this)